# How to use value of state in a JSX expression in a functional React component?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I would like to use a value of a state variable in a JSX expression and cannot figure out the syntax. Here is simplified code:

```
function App() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  return (
    <div>
          {isLoading ? `Loading...` : 'Load Page ' + {page}}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If `isLoading` is false, I would like the output to say **Load Page 1**.

As of now it says **Load Page [object Object]** and I am stuck on the syntax.

Thanks.

Comment: `{isLoading ? `Loading...` : 'Load Page ' + page}` stop adding `{}` everywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{isLoading ? `Loading...` : 'Load Page ' + page}
```

stop adding `{}` everywhere

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
{isLoading ? `Loading...` :`Load Page ${page}`}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    function App() {
      const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
      const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

      return <div>{isLoading ? `Loading...` : `Load Page ${page + 1}`}</div>;
    }

    export default App;
```

Comment: The other answer worked for the question I posed, but I ACTUALLY ended up using this answer in my code because it allowed me to add 1 to the current 'page' counter: `Load Page ${page+1}`, which is what I needed in my actual code (instead of the sample posted here). THANK YOU.

Comment: sure, you can add + 1 too. I update the answer